# Can I enable mouse/desktop-like text selection behavior in an Android app?

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-arc

I'm using ARC Welder to turn my Android app into a Chrome OS app. Most of it works perfectly, except that text selection with a mouse behaves like it would on a touch device, requiring long-clicking or double-clicking on words, and then dragging the ends. Is there a way around this?

Comment: AFAIK, that's Android's standard behavior, even if you are using an external mouse or keyboard.

Comment: @CommonsWare that does appear to be the case. Maybe it's possible to override that behavior with some of the mouse APIs available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CommonsWare points out, this is the Android behavior.

Feel free to [file a bug](http://goo.gl/megdlG) even for a feature request. 
We are open to allowing the behavior to be changed, but it also seems like something that should be left up to the end user (how do they expect to interact with an Android app on a Chromebook?)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was going to try to work around it before I filed a feature request, but after testing today in Chrome 47.0.2503.0 (dev), I'm seeing the text selection behavior I was looking for (at least in EditTexts). Looks great.